# How do I create objects in main from a single linked list header file

Tags: c++

Im trying to create an object so I can use functions from header files based on a linked list. the errors that I'm getting on Visual Studio are C2955,C2133,and C2512.

All I have been doing so far is rearranging where templates go.

```
//list.h
#define LIST_H
#include "node.h"

template<typename T>
class List  //single linked list
{
private:
     node<T> head; 
     node<T> tail;
     int numofNodes;

public:

    List() {   //constructor
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        //temp = NULL;
        numofNodes = 0;
    }

    /functions for add,delete,display,search,etc/
};
#endif


//main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "node.h"
#include "List.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include "currency.h"
using namespace std;

int main()

{ 
    List obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the full error messages as verbatim text please. Those numbers are meaningless for most of us. Also we need to see a [mcve] in order to help you.

Comment: Hint: There's no type named `List`, but there is a *template* with that name. Just about any book or tutorial (or class) should have taught you how to use templates, and if not then go back to the book or tutorial (or class-notes) and read again.

Comment: Are you trying to create a linked list implementation for a homework assignment, or do you want to simply create a list of objects?  Based on your statement, `Im trying to create an object`, you have told us that this is not an effort to create a list implementation?

Answer (score 0):

When using templates, you need to specify the type:

```
std::vector<float> f;
std::List<int> my_list;
std::list<double> my_list;
```

The data type used in the *instantiation* of the `template` is between `<` and `>`.

Search your favorite C++ reference for *instantiating* [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).